# Function for add minutes

Tags: javascript

I need to add minutes in an specif hour.
It is in js.
I have a hour = 09:30 and need to add more 30minutes, but the output shows me '10:0', one '0' less.

```
Soma_minutos: function(hour, minutes) {
// This case  minutes = 30;  hour = 09:30


    var tempo, hora_nova, horas = '';

    tempo     = new Date("T"+hora);
    tempo.setTime(tempo.getTime() + minutos*60000);
    horas     = tempo.getHours().toString(); // 10
    minutos   = tempo.getMinutes().toString(); // 0

    hora_nova = horas + ':' + minutos;

    return hora_nova;

},
```

Comment: @dot.Py Its more of a *format number in 2 digits* question

Comment: I'd suggest using [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) for all date time manipulation.

Comment: You go do this `hora_nova = ('0'+horas).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0'+minutos).slice(-2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
if (minotos.length = 1)
{
    minotos = "0" + minotos;
}
```

Comment: tell me it that's what you were looking for

Comment: Yes, that is, but I'd like to use just the Date functions. However, it works.